# Debugging python function

Tags: python

I am having trouble to get my function to work. My functions needs to be a parameter which accepts `*Asterisk` characters and will print out 1 asterisk, 3 ast., 5, any odd numbers in the subsequent lines. So first line will have 1 ast, second line 3 ast., and so on. The parameter will accept any odd `int`.

My attempt:

```
def arrowHead(n):
    spaces = n / 2
    for x in range(1, n+2, 2):
        string_ln = ''
    for num in range(spaces):
        string_ln = string_ln + ' '
    for num2 in range(x): string_ln = string_ln + '*'
        spaces = spaces - 1
        print string_ln
        final_string = ''
    for x in range(n / 2):
        final_string = final_string + ' '
        final_string = final_string + '*'
    for x in range(3):
        print final_string
```

Comment: You haven't told us what's not working.

Comment: @mVChr no, its sample test problems I am going over for before my test on Monday.

Comment: The line `for num2 in range(x): string_ln = string_ln + '*'` is an obvious error. The `string_ln = string_ln + '*'` should be part of the indented code block below it.

Answer (score 4):

You're not going to be able to print an arrow head this way, because you can't print characters in between spaces!

You could try something like this?

```
def arrow(n):
  for x in range(n+1):
    print (' '*n)+(' *'*x)
    n -= 1

>> arrow(7)
>> 
       *
      * *
     * * *
    * * * *
   * * * * *
  * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much ! I see what I did wrong. One last question, how can I get the arrow head to look like a diamond instead of a pryamind?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can figure that out from here, The code I've given you is 3 lines, and you need to do the the opposite. If this answer is right for the original question then accept it and ask another one if you need to.

Comment: Is there a reason it's askew instead of having `(' *'*x)` without the extra space?

Comment: Whoops yeah sorry, copied the wrong test from the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug a Python script, you can use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). For example, in your system's shell or command line:

```
python -m pdb yourscript.py
```

You can then step through your script using `n` (which skips function calls), `s` (which steps into function calls), print the state of variables using `p yourvarname`, and use several other commands (try using `help` to see them all and then `help somecommand` to see detailed help).

Answer (score 0):

Not clear with your question, but if you want to print asterisk odd number of times, go with this

```
def arrowHead(n):
   print '*' * (2*n-1)
```

Update:-

```
>>> def arrow(n,flag=1):
    if flag<n:
        print (' '*(arrow(n,flag+1))+' * '*(n-(2*flag-1)))
    return 2*flag-1

>>> arrow(10)




            * 
          *  *  * 
        *  *  *  *  * 
      *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
    *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

Comment: Thank you! But, how can I get the arrow head to look like a diamond instead of a pryamind? Like it is arrowhead(9) you will have one ast. first line , 2 second line, 3 third line, 2 fourth line and 1 in the last line?